# JWT Authentication Failed

Tags: node.js, authentication, jwt

Every time when I try to test the text on API in terms of backend tweets after login the user it throws me the same error as you see. It's showing my desired output in a curl Code snippet but throwing an error in a body. Here is my repo GitHub - naima-shk/Twitter-Clone

[image]
[image]
TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFK5c.png):

Comment: Here's a [full example](https://github.com/jmchaves/node-passport-jwt-example-app/blob/master/routes/auth.js) of how to use passport-jwt. Good luck!

Comment: @Nir Alfasi Thank you But this example does not works in my case. Can you please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're experiencing this issue is because you accidentally misspelled strategy in line 1 of your passport.js file.

Also unrelated to your problem, but you no longer need to use bodyparser, instead you can simply use

```
app.use(express.json())
```

Comment: I correct the spelling but the error is still there. Now it's throwing this error ``TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined``

Comment: Which javascript file and which line does the error point to?

Comment: I have fixed the Type error but itis still throwing  Jwt error 'Error: Unknown authentication strategy &quot;jwt&quot;<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at attempt '