# Every time when I test my tweet api it throws this to me ''TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined''

Tags: node.js, api, postman

When I test the tweet Api on postman it throws this to me.  Here's my repo link: https://github.com/naima-shk/Twitter-Clone
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in file:
https://github.com/naima-shk/Twitter-Clone/blob/master/routes/api/tweet.js#L19

In the code below (see the code comment I added):

```
router.post("/",
(res,req) => { // <== THE BUG IS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!
    const {isValid, errors} = validateTweetInput(req.body);
    if(!isValid){
        return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }
    const newTweet = new Tweet ({
      user:req.user.id,
      text:req.body.texta
    });

    newTweet.save().then(tweet => res.json(tweet));
})
```

Explanation: the req/res are passed in the opposite order, so the code is treating the response as the request and vice verse.

Modify that line to: `(req, res) => {` and I believe the code will start working ;)

Comment: I tried this but it does not work for me atleatst.

Comment: @NaimaShaikh answer corrected, please try again

Comment: I tried again but it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: @NaimaShaikh please post a `curl` of the request. You can generate the curl request from postman by clicking on the "code" link on the right side of the screen (and a bit above the middle). In order to help you I need to reproduce the exact same request you're using.

Comment: curl --location --request POST 'localhost:5000/api/tweet' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/javascript' \
--data-raw '{ 
    data: { 
        text: '\''bla'\'' 
    }, 

}'

Comment: The curl on postman shows this curl --location --request POST 'localhost:5000/api/tweet/' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'Text='\''this is naima'\'''  But the body shows this Error: Unknown authentication strategy &quot;jwt&quot;<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at attempt

Comment: @NaimaShaikh now this is a different problem than what you describe in the original post. Sounds like this bug solved the original problem and now you're running into a different bug further away in the code. Please _separate_ the issues and post a new question for the other problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66091341/jwt-authenctication-failed/66179582?noredirect=1#comment117091250_66179582  here is the question